# Configure themes programmatically

Tags: linux, linux-mint, desktop-customization, themes, cinnamon

I'm trying to create a bash script which setups my environment. I would like to change icon, desktop and control themes using bash commands. This can be done by hand in this panel:

[image: Theme configuration panel]

Which commands would allow me to change these settings? Where could I find documentation for these commands?

I am using `Linux Mint 18.2 Cinnamon 64-bit`.

**Edit**

Here are the commands which can change all of these settings which are shown in the screen-cap:

```bsh
# Window borders.
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.wm.preferences theme '...'

# Icons.
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.interface icon-theme '...'

# Controls.
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.interface gtk-theme '...'

# Mouse pointer.
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.interface cursor-theme '...'

# Desktop.
gsettings set org.cinnamon.theme name '...'
```

Comment: Welcome on SuperUser Edd... find some second to read [ask], each site is a little different.... In the case of this question I think is relevant to specify  the desktop environment you are using, because of course the answer depends on this. BTW you have an answer.

Comment: @Hastur Thanks for the note, I have added the `desktop` tag and am trying out the answer as we speak.

Comment: You're welcome, but I meant [Desktop_environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment) not desktop... Gnome (which one), KDE, Cinnamon, Xfce,LxDe,LXQt... see on google `desktop environment linux`... maybe when you find yours you can replace one of the tag with the specific one (gnome, mate...)

Comment: @Hastur My desktop environment is `cinnamon`. I've removed the `desktop` tag and replaced it with `cinnamon` (since the limit is 5 tags).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several pages that can help you online.<sup>[[1a](http://linuxxcommand.blogspot.ru/2014/01/changing-gtk-themes-via-command-line.html),[1b](http://www.fandigital.com/2012/06/change-theme-command-line-gnome.html),...]</sup>
Assuming you are using gnome

> ### 1 - Change GTK Theme
>
> **Unity, Gnome 3 Shell/Classic, Cinnamon**
>
> ```
> gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme "Mytheme"
> ```
>
> **Mate**
>
> ```
> mateconftool-2 --type=string --set /desktop/mate/interface/gtk_theme "Mytheme"
> ```
>
> **Gnome 2**
>
> ```
> gconftool-2 --type=string --set /desktop/gnome/interface/gtk_theme "Mytheme"
> ```

On the link provided above<sup>[[1a](http://linuxxcommand.blogspot.ru/2014/01/changing-gtk-themes-via-command-line.html)]</sup> there are other sections about

1. Change GTK Theme
2. Change window theme (Metacity)
3. Change Shell theme
4. Change GTK color scheme

You can find info on the command with the usual way, internet searching for `gsettings`<sup>[[2](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/gsettings-tool.html)]</sup>,`gconftool-2`<sup>[[3](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gconftool-2)]</sup>, `mateconftool-2`<sup>[[4](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-mateconftool-2/)]</sup>  or the *holy* `man`:

```
man gsettings
man gconftool-2
man mateconftool-2
```

---

You may find interesting pages with a google search, for example, with the following keywords

```
linux mint change theme command line
```

Comment: `gsettings` is the one. With the help of `man` I found the required keys to change all the settings which I've provided in the screen-cap (even though only one key worked from the articles that you've posted). I'm accepting your answer and updating my question with the commands that I've found.

Comment: @Edd In general, when it is possible and it doesn't create too much confusion, we try to give a more general answer to solve not only the problem of the OP but even of the other travellers that may eventually finish on this page... BTW _"only one key worked"_ because by default you may have only one of that command installed and it depends on which _desktop environment_ you have: Unity, Gnome 3 Shell/Classic, __Cinnamon__ -->`gsettings`<--, mate `mateconftool-2`, Gnome-2 `gconftool-2`...

Comment: That doesn't work. There is no such directory as /desktop/ in MATE in Debian 9 for instance. I run that line of code and I don't get anything.

Comment: I tried changing themes for `gimp` but none of the above works... Why is that?